# Extract frequency per month per ID from a weird format

Tags: excel, date, mariadb, frequency

I need your help regarding the following problem:
I hope I describe it correctly as I got reprimanded last time. If some points are still unclear, just ask.

The problem is:

I have an Excel table where there are the following columns:

•   ID

•   Start date

•   End date

•   Frequency

Now I want to extract the frequency per month per ID. 
The problem is that the periods are not uniform AND the start date is not necessarily a Monday and the end date is not necessarily a Sunday.
What complicates the problem further is that the frequency is in the following format:

1.3.5..

12.....

..3.567

Every number describes one weekday (1 – Monday, 2 – Tuesday, 3 – Wednesday, etc.), so 1.3..6. stands for three occurrences (on Monday, Wednesday, Saturday).

What is the smartest way to get to the frequency per month?
I have the following tools available:

- Excel 2013
- Access 2013
- MariaDB with MySQL workbench

I know that you can do it in Excel with a lot of manual work, but I guess that there is a smarter approach.
How would you approach the problem?

Best regards

Edit:
To be more precise about the problem regarding the uniform periods, please take a look at the picture attached: [Example of not uniform periods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAHM4.png)

So I can't just take the occurrences per week and multiply them by 4.

Comment: I see a problem with QW35 ... date difference is 1 day, but frequency is 1 & 6 ... and in TR45 only 7 .. does this mean each week on day 7 or only once ... how to interpret all this ... a precise formulation of the problem is half of the solution (see below)?

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your answer. You are right the example makes no sense. The frequency can be max. the date difference. This was my fault, as I created the example. Unfortunately I still don't know how to count the frequency per month in a smart way without a lot of manual work.

Comment: now we need to establish whether begin/end dates are always on fixed week days (e.g. MON & SUN respectively), then we could calculate the week number to represent the period and find nice ways to assign these to months ... maybe you can close this Q and raise a new one like "assign periods to months" ... let's have some realistic sample data and we might be able to help you more

Answer (score 0):

This is not a weird format ;) ... if you want to "calculate the number of occurences of any numeric characters" in your frequency string, you can use a combination of `SUBSTITUTE()` and `LEN()`.

1. Substitute all "." by nothing ("")
2. count the length of the remaining string

With your argument in C3, it looks like `=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C3,".",""))`

Now you have numeric values in a row and can manipulate them further (sum per period, average, etc., pivot tables, charts, ...)

[image]

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your answer. That's a very nice approach and it actually already solves one of my two problems. So with your approach I have the occurrences per week. Now I still need to find out the frequency per month and as the periods (Start date to End date) are not uniform, this does not seem to be too easy. I will modify my question to illustrate that problem more precisely.